# Which one of these two methods should I use to stop correctly a scheduled thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I created a simple task, to run every two minutes, that I want to stop once a boolean becomes true.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledxecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(drawRunnable , 0, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I've been lurking around stackoverflow and I basically found that I need to use either `scheduledFuture.cancel(false)` or `scheduledExecutor.shutdown()`.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

scheduledExecutor.shutdown() is the better choice b'coz it gracefully starts the shutdown of all the tasks submitted whereas scheduledFuture.cancel(false) only deals with that particular task only.

- [ExecutorService.shutdown() Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown())
- [Future.cancel(boolean) Java
  Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean))

Answer (score 0):

If the executor service has no tasks, it remains still alive and is ready to be used again. Some resources remain blocked. If you use the executor for this single task only, then better is to use `scheduledExecutor.shutdown()`. It will wait until the current tasks are completed and will not start new ones. So it is safe to call it even if the task is running at the moment.

But if you add some more tasks to this executor service, it is better to cancel a particular task only. Then you will be sure that you don't cancel any other tasks.